# Xamarin forms Listview within a listview with actions per item on child list

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I need to create the following view (HTML design)
[Final Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHPJv.png)

The data is as follows, and we are just not able to get a ListView working to do this:

> {  "chronicScripts": [
>           {
>               "forName": "MR JOHN DOE",  "scriptNumber": 4000000,  "scriptDate": "2020-04-27T00:00:00",  "chronics": [
>                   {
>                       "description": "TAMSUL 0.4MG SR  CAP",  "order": "order",  },
>                   {
>                       "description": "STORWIN 20MG     TAB",  "order": "order",  },
>                   {
>                       "description": "COXLEON 200MG    CAP",  "order": "order",  }
>               ]
>           },
>           {
>               "forName": " JANE DOE",  "scriptNumber": 4800001,  "scriptDate": "2020-04-27T00:00:00",  "chronics": [
>                   {
>                       "description": "CILODEX EAR DROPS",  "order": "order",  },
>                   {
>                       "description": "VUSOR 5MG        TAB",  "order": "order",  },
>                   {
>                       "description": "MIZART 40MG      TAB",  "order": "order",  },
>                   {
>                       "description": "ELTROXIN NF 0.1MG",  "order": "order",  }
>               ]
>           }
>       ] }

Can you please advise how we can achieve such a design with what controls

[LISTVIEW (chronicscripts)]

[HEADER

[LISTVIEW (chronicscripts.chronics)]

[DETAILS

Comment: nested ListViews are a **horrible** idea.  Try grouping instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I solved this problem using teleriks RadListView collection and the telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl.

Comment: You could share your solution as answer and accept it , which will help more people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<telerikDataControls:RadListView
    x:Name="chronicProfileListView"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Chronics.ChronicScripts}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ChronicScriptsDataModel">
            <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                <telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                    <Frame
                        Margin="0,0,0,10"
                        Padding="0,0,0,5"
                        BorderColor="LightGray"
                        HasShadow="False">
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Padding="0,15,0,15"
                                BackgroundColor="#17469e"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span
                                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                    FontSize="15"
                                                    Text="{Binding ForName}"
                                                    TextColor="White">
                                                    <Span.FontFamily>
                                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Futura" />
                                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Futura-Bookfont.ttf#Futura-Bookfont" />
                                                        </OnPlatform>
                                                    </Span.FontFamily>
                                                </Span>
                                                <Span
                                                    FontSize="15"
                                                    Text=" | "
                                                    TextColor="White">
                                                    <Span.FontFamily>
                                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Futura" />
                                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Futura-Bookfont.ttf#Futura-Bookfont" />
                                                        </OnPlatform>
                                                    </Span.FontFamily>
                                                </Span>
                                                <Span
                                                    FontSize="15"
                                                    Text="{Binding ScriptNumber}"
                                                    TextColor="White">
                                                    <Span.FontFamily>
                                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Futura" />
                                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Futura-Bookfont.ttf#Futura-Bookfont" />
                                                        </OnPlatform>
                                                    </Span.FontFamily>
                                                </Span>
                                                <Span
                                                    FontSize="15"
                                                    Text=" | "
                                                    TextColor="White">
                                                    <Span.FontFamily>
                                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Futura" />
                                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Futura-Bookfont.ttf#Futura-Bookfont" />
                                                        </OnPlatform>
                                                    </Span.FontFamily>
                                                </Span>
                                                <Span
                                                    FontSize="15"
                                                    Text="{Binding ScriptDate}"
                                                    TextColor="White">
                                                    <Span.FontFamily>
                                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Futura" />
                                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="Futura-Bookfont.ttf#Futura-Bookfont" />
                                                        </OnPlatform>
                                                    </Span.FontFamily>
                                                </Span>
                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>

                            <!--  Display items per Order  -->
                            <telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Chronics, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                SelectionMode="Single">
                                <telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ChronicDataModel">
                                        <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
                                            <views:ChronicMainItemTemplate />
                                        </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </telerikDataControls:NonVirtualizedItemsControl>

                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
            </telerikListView:ListViewTemplateCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
</telerikDataControls:RadListView>
```